# PCL and ROS Hydro Symbol Lookup Error

Tags: ros, pcl, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a ROS package that depends on PCL. The package compiles without problems. However, when running the code, the following error appears:

> symbol lookup error: /home/andreas/baxter_ws/devel/lib/libaffordances_lib.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3pcl6search6KdTreeINS_8PointXYZEEC1Eb

I assume that this is related to the KDTree class and wrong linking(?). The CMakeLists.txt and package.xml contain what is described here, http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Migration#PCL, at the end of the section.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/144176/pcl-and-ros-hydro-symbol-lookup-error/) by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 529 on 2014-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you check 'sudo apt-get install -f"   and clean and rebuild your workspace like http://answers.ros.org/question/121266/undefined-symbol/#121291

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rebuilding solved it. Thanks!

---

Originally posted by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) with karma: 529 on 2014-03-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1